# Submitting data from PeopleEditor control in Web Part gives error

Tags: web-part, visual-web-part, people-picker, visual-studio-2013

I have a web part that submits data to a list and it uses a PeopleEditor control for selecting users.

Once user is selected, when I submit the form it gives following error

> Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are
>   trying to update may be read only.

I have included tag prefix as

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Control is inserted as

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="a" runat="server"  PrincipalSource="All" SharePointGroup="Everyone" MultiSelect="false" />
```

And on click of a submit button-

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPListCollection vlist = web.Lists;

SPList list = web.Lists[new Guid("{xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}")];
SPListItem listitem = list.Items.Add();
listitem["FormCompletedBy"] = a.ResolvedEntities;
listitem.Update();
```

Where

```
FormCompletedBy
```

is a field in SharePoint List where the data is to be submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save User data as below

```
string[] userarray = a.CommaSeparatedAccounts.ToString().Split(',');;
SPFieldUserValueCollection usercollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();

for (int i = 0; i < userarray.Length; i++)
{
     SPFieldUserValue usertoadd = ConvertLoginAccount(userarray[i]);
     usercollection.Add(usertoadd);
}
listItem["FormCompletedBy"] = usercollection;
listItem.Update();

public SPFieldUserValue ConvertLoginAccount(string userid)
{
    SPFieldUserValue uservalue;
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
       {
          SPUser requireduser = web.EnsureUser(userid);
          uservalue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, requireduser.ID, requireduser.LoginName);
       }
    }
    return uservalue;
}
```